# Is there a psql equivalent of bash's reverse-search-history?

Tags: postgresql, psql, mac-os-x, command-line

I am very fond of [`bash`'s reverse-search-history (C-r)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html) (command-line feature):

> Search backward starting at the current line and moving ‘up’ through the history as necessary. This is an incremental search.

When I hit `control-r` in `bash`, I get the following:

```
(reverse-i-search)`':
```

And I am able to type characters of previously executed commands, honing in on what I am looking for. If I make a mistake, I can enter `control-h` to erase a character (equivalent of `backspace`).

This command-line functionality makes it extremely easy to refer to previously executed commands. I am wondering if such a capability exists for `psql`. I find it extremely inefficient to rely on just `control-p` and `control-n`.

For what it's worth, I am using `PostgreSQL 9.3.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn), 64-bit` - obtained via [Postgres.app](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/releases).

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl-r` already? :)

Comment: Of course, and it has no effect for me. Are you suggesting `ctrl-r` works for you??

Comment: Use `rlwrap`...

Comment: I installed `rlwrap` via homebrew (`brew install rlwrap`) and tried it out (`rlwrap psql`) - but `control-r` still does not work; in fact, it behaves in the exact same way as `control-r` without `rlwrap` (which is that *nothing happens*). Perhaps this is the sign of a deeper problem.

Comment: `ctrl-r` is normally provided by the readline library. It appears there's an [open issue](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/144) for postgres.app about this.

Comment: @user664833 well, yes.  Note that I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: I use homebrew's postgresql's `/usr/local/bin/psql` and reverse-search works great.

Answer (score 23):

[A conversation about this on GitHub led to an interim "quick fix" solution](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/144):

> open `~/.editrc` and add:
>
> `bind "^R" em-inc-search-prev`

Apparently the bigger issue is that PostgresApp uses `libedit` instead of `libreadline`. And supposedly `libedit` lacks some command-line features of `libreadline`, so until PostgresApp is compiled against `libreadline`, just use the above quick fix.

Comment: Do you have to be in psql to use it?